# Why do I get a green image when I convert an RGB image to grayscale using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

When I tried to convert an RGB image with OpenCV function cv2.cvtColor(), I got a green-like image.

I've converted the raw image read by OpenCV to RGB-format, again converted it to gray scale using cv2.cvtColor(), and tried to display it using pyplot.imshow() function.

```py
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: You have to explicitly set the [`cmap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) (colormap) parameter to `gray`, i.e. use `plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')`. The default is `viridis`, obviously some green-ish/blue-ish colormap.

Comment: Thanks! Now I set the cmap parameter to gray and it works. Previously I thought that the default setting would be gray instead of some other color cuz it feels more natural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`plt.imgshow()` uses a color map for a single-channel images. You have two possible solutions, convert your grayscale to rgb (basically duplicate the grayscale 3 times), or choose a proper colormap as explained here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

[image: linear colormaps]

Comment: Thank you! Now I choose the cmap parameter to be gray and it works.